# "Append" the Add/Plus icon to an NSImage during dragging

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsimage

I have implemented drag-n-drop in a custom Calendar view in my application, which does a good job of providing support for *moving* items around.

But, I would like to add visual support for *copying* items. I have already implemented this in the back-end (when the Option key is held down) but I would like to supplement the feature with a more context-sensitive icon.

I have an `NSImage` created from the event, as displayed in my Calendar. This makes it seem as though the actual item is being dragged. (Which is nice!):

```
NSImage *i = ...;

...

[self dragImage:i at:thePoint offset:NSZeroSize event:theEvent pasteboard:pboard source:nil slideBack:NO];
```

But, in a situation where the user is holding down the Option key, I'd like to superimpose the "plus" or "copy" green plus icon over the top of my `NSImage` so it is apparent that the drop will result in a copy.

Is there any easy way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement `draggingEntered:` and/or `draggingUpdated:` in your view and return `NSDragOperationCopy` to get a green plus icon automatically.